# What is the best performing general purpose data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking to create a library where one of the functions users need to do is store and retrieve data, along with an index.I don't know which they'll be doing more of: inserting, reading/writing, deleting, or random searching.

What kind of data structure would you use so they get the best performance in general? How would your proposed data structure compare performance wise in each scenario?

Thinking hash table or avl tree? Or something like a combo of data structures? Linked list of arrays?

What would be cool is if it self optimized, so it sees the user is doing more inserts or reads or random searches, so future inserts are optimized for that.

Comment: _best performing general purpose data structure_? Simple List and Array. I bet they are used 90% of the time by all developers all over the world. Almost every language has them by default.

Answer (score 2):

There's no single best data structure out there that does this or I'd promise that *everyone* would be using it. However, there are a couple of very reasonable options available.

The first question to think about is *what do you need to do with the data?* If you're just storing items and looking them up later on, and all you need to do is add, remove, and look up items, then you might want to look more toward various flavors of hash tables. On the other hand, if you're looking for the ability to process items in sorted order, then hash tables are probably out and you should probably look more toward balanced trees.

The next question is what type of data you're storing. If each item has some associated key, what kind of key is it? Both hash tables and BSTs are great in general, but more specialized data structures exist as well that work specifically for string keys (tries) and other types like integers.

From there you should think about how much data you're storing. If you're storing a couple hundred megabytes and things fit comfortably in RAM, you might not need to do anything special here. But if you have a truly huge amount of data and things don't fit into RAM, you'll need to look into external data structures like B-trees.

Another question to consider is what kind of performance guarantees you want. Most hash tables require some sort of dynamic resizing as the number of items increases, which can lead to infrequent but expensive rebuild operations that can slow things down. If you absolutely need real-time performance, this won't work for you. If you're okay with that, then go for it!

And let's suppose you've then narrowed things down to, say, "a hash table" or "a balanced BST." Now you have to select which type to use! For hash tables, simple structures like linear probing hash tables or chained hashing often need some performance tuning to be maximally efficient. Newer approaches like cuckoo hashing can give better memory performance in some cases, while engineered approaches like Google's `flat_hash_map` are extremely optimized for the x86 architecture. For BSTs, you might want something like an AVL tree if you have way more lookups than insertions or deletions, since AVL trees have a low height, but you might also want to look at red/black trees if insertions and deletions are more common, and perhaps into more modern trees like RAVL or WAVL trees if you really have a lot of deletions.

All of this is to say that the answer is "it depends." The more you know about your particular application, the better a data structure you'll be able to pick. And, sadly, there is no One Data Structure To Rule Them All. :-)